# Arabic text showing not properly in the file of s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have uploaded the csv to s3 with rails, but the issue is, that file contained have arabic names, so when i open that csv file directly from s3 console, its showing the arabic names as gibberish, i have attached that **image**   here

[image]

also i tried to add that "charset utf", but its showing as same, is there any workaround for this?

This is the code i have been using

```
def to_s3(data, filename)
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  puts "......#{data.encoding.name}" #UTF-8
  my_bucket = s3.buckets[ENV['BKT_NAME']]
  my_bucket.objects.create(filename, data)
  exp_url = object.url_for(:read, { expires: 
  Exp::EXPIRE, response_content_type: "text/csv", 
  response_content_disposition: "attachment;filename=#{filename}.csv"
  }).to_s
end
```

and with this **exp_url** i am composing the download link to download that csv, when open that csv in my system that arabic names show as gibberish. Also i have opened that csv directly from s3 console, there also showing like this Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø§Ù†Ø¨ÙŠØ©

this is the url i have put for download, is anything do that in this url

```
url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"+BKT_NAME+"/"+file_url+"&response-
content-disposition=attachment;filename={filename}.csv&response-
content-type=text/csv"

<td><%= link_to 'Download', url %></td>
```

Comment: When you say "the file have arabic names" do you mean that the **filename** of the csv is arabic/utf8 or do you mean that some of the text contained in the csv is arabic/utf8?

Comment: thanks, i mean the text contained in that csv is arabic, above i have attached that file content

Comment: I can't see an attachment , just a screengrab which isn't very useful.  Are you sure that the csv has been saved in utf8 format?

Comment: Actually when the time to create the csv , i have used like this 
return CSV.generate(:encoding => "UTF-8") do |csv|  end. but when i look into that csv direclty in s3, its shows as gibberish, like this Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù‚Ø¨Ù‘Ù„Ø§Øª ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø£Ø·Ø¨Ø§Ù‚

Comment: What gem do you use for S3 uploads?

Comment: is there any way to add the utf when download that file from s3 @MaxWilliams, because just before going to s3, its showing the data as UTF.

Comment: When you say "its showing the data as UTF" can you explain how you are getting this information, and EXACTLY what it says?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, i have  updated my question with what exactly is happening

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about the formatting of the original file.  I can see how you are uploading and downloading from S3.  Forget about S3 for now, and just look at the file sitting on your computer waiting to be uploaded.  How do you know it's UTF-8 formatted?

Comment: actually i put the data with puts "......#{data.encoding.name}", its showing utf-8, sorry, is there any other way to check that? i have been checking all the ways